# Ultra Low Power servo and controller for long usage..?

Tags: microcontroller, servomotor, battery, amperage

So I have an idea which would require the following:

1-4 servos
1 microcontroller
some way of communicating with it via smartphone (bluetooth or wifi)

Ability to run for 14 days on a small power source 2-3AA or AAA battries.

I'm seeing a lot of boards run in the 200Ma range which makes using batteries look like a no go as this even with a 13000mAh pack will only last 65hrs or about 3 days or so.

If I were able to get into thee micro amp range this would be great or very low mA range. Servos should only have to run <1second about 2-3 times a day.

Looking for starter information on this.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* BostonMacOSX, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: As it stands, there isn't enough information to answer your question. The easiest way to evaluate capacity requirements is to do a power analysis. You don't specify how many servos you're using or how they're loaded, what power state you're keeping your wireless connection in, which wireless standard you're using, what microcontroller you're using, etc. Once you can specify that equipment, you can multiply the rated current for the equipment by their rated voltages to get a rated power. Multiply the rated power by the desired run time to get the energy requirements.

Comment: If you would like more assistance with this question, please *edit the question* to include the missing information listed above. If you would like to *discuss* your design problem, please join us in [chat].

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using an arduino pro mini, after disabling the power LED. [This Article](http://www.home-automation-community.com/arduino-low-power-how-to-run-atmega328p-for-a-year-on-coin-cell-battery/) claims a power consumption of 0.0232 mA in power down sleep. However, adding BLE will increase power consumption greatly. I'd look into alternative solutions, such as solar power.

Comment: It will be an indoor application.....which kinda limits that...no outlet though so battery is needed.